# Filters of Django REST Framework inside GET function?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way of using the Django REST filters inside a **`GET`** function I created?

It works when I use this:

```
class ContactListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserContactListSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'last_name',)
```

But I want it to work in the **GET** function I created:

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    contacts = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serializer = UserContactListSerializer(contacts)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'last_name',)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: When you say "It works when I use this"... doesn't it work with a GET request?

Comment: Not quite. It works with the GET code on, but the way i want it to work is only through the GET function.

Comment: Then I think you need to write the filtering code yourself. You can read [this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/filters.py) code for implementing this on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a Get function...

Say you had a URL like `mywebsite.com/mypage/?search=[searchterm]`

then in your GET function use this:

```
def get(self, request):
    filterurl = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)
    contacts = Profile.objects.all()
    if filterurl is not None:
        contacts = Profile.objects.filter([fieldname]=filterurl)
    return Response(contacts)
```

Comment: This code won't work. Where does `pk` come from? What's the point of the second line at all?

Comment: Where doesn't it work? If there is a query param in the url than that param will filter the queryset. Would love to know. Thanks!

Comment: Now it will work, because you edited the problematic line.

Answer (score -1):

In get function, the View is an instance. So filter_backends is a property of this instance. You must reupdate the property of its and call "filter_queryset" function. "filter_backends" will be used in this function.:

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    self.filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    self.search_fields = ('name', 'last_name',)
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()) 
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)  
    return Response(serializer.data)
```