# Django Rest Framework get filtered queryset in custom get function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

So I have an `APIView` like this:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyAPIView(APIView):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [MyCustomFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ["field1", "field2"]

    def get(self, request):
        s = StatManager(self.queryset)
        return Response(s.dashboard())
```

where I filter bunch of stuff using `MyCustomFilterBackend` and `DjangoFilterBackend`. My goal is to give the filtered queryset to `StatManager` so it generates stats for the dashboard.

Currently, `s = StatManager(self.queryset)` does not take filters into account. How can I provide the filtered queryset in my `get` function?

I read the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering). I was expecting for `APIView` to have some function like `get_filtered_queryset()`.

I read [Filters of Django REST Framework inside GET function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321544/filters-of-django-rest-framework-inside-get-function)
and [DJango filter_queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843838/django-filter-queryset) but they have no adequate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `self.queryset` in `filter_queryset()` method inside `get()` method so:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyAPIView(APIView):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [MyCustomFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ["field1", "field2"]

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
            queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
        return queryset

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.queryset)
        s = StatManager(queryset)
        return Response(s.dashboard())
```

Comment: This throws `MyAPIView object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'` error.

Comment: It is working now after adding the filter_queryset function. This can be considered as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843838/django-filter-queryset?noredirect=1&lq=1)